# SPIM equivalent for x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, mips, simulator

Having learned MIPS, it was super helpful to write simple code and testing it out with SPIM. Being able to see all the registers and stepping through the code really helped me understand what each instruction did. Is there an equivalent emulator for x86 language where I can just load some simple codes and look at each registers and step through each instructions?

I learn best by doing and replicating codes on the lecture.

I used window version of SPIM.

An GUI simulator will be preferred over working on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an emulator for x86, but it will give you all the debugging options and what not.

I'd use Microsoft Visual C++ and MASM. [Here's a tutorial for how to get all that set up.](http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2010/) MSVC++ comes with great tools for debugging assembly code; your basic breakpoints, step through options, and other windows such as disassembly (for looking at the generated machine code), registers window, memory window, watch windows, and the list goes on.